# Scoping issue with anonymous functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js, anonymous-function, scoping

I'm learning some WebGL concepts using javascript and the Three.js library, but I've hit a bit of a snag trying to figure out how to use the [OBJLoader](http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js) to load a .obj file using classes. Heres the code:

```
Model.prototype.loadModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    loader.load( this.modelPath, function ( object ) {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material.map = self.modelTexture;
            }
        });
        self.modelObj = object;
        console.log(self.modelObj); // Returns [Object object]
    });
        console.log(self.modelObj); // Returns undefined

    this.modelObj = self.modelObj;
    this.modelObj.position.x = this.x;
    this.modelObj.position.y = this.y;
    this.modelObj.position.z = this.z;
}
```

I cant get the object to use as `this.modelObj` out of the anonymous function and I think it's a scope issue. Trying to add `this.modelObj` to the function parameters results in "missing formal parameter" and using `this.` inside the function thinks its inside the scope of the function ( or loader )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a *callback* be invoked when the loading is completed, add the *callback* as a parameter to your function:

```
Model.prototype.loadModel = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    loader.load(this.modelPath, function (object) { // inner function will be called on success
        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
            {
                child.material.map = self.modelTexture;
            }
        });

        self.modelObj = object;
        callback(object); // pass loaded object to callback function
    });
}
```

When you do it this way you separate the loading logic from the *callback*, where you will actually consume/use the data you have loaded.
Imagine you have multiple cases like these, you won't have to write that loading logic (the inner *success* function) over and over again.

The XHR (used in AJAX) also accepts an error function and requires your functions to check for a `readystate` variable. I don't know if that applies to this loader, too. But if you can, you should implement the error case as well.

Comment: I'd rather will use `callback(self);` as there already instance of `object` in `self.modelObj`

Comment: Yes, this may be a good idea, but it really depends on how you want to expose your inner guts to the callback. A simple rule is *as least as possible*, so `self` might be too much. I really don't know but I appreciate pointing this weakness out.

Comment: You store `this` in `that` variable, but not using it, and `self` refers to `window` object, so you define `modelObj` as global.

Comment: Oops! `that` should have been `self`! This was a major error, thank you very much for helping me out, sir :)

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, should I define a callback function every time I use `loadModel()`? or can I just use `callback(object)` inside the function to load `object` to a member inside the Model class? Sorry for being so dumb about this

Comment: You can do both, define an actual `function` and pass that every time you want -and- have some exceptional cases where you don't pass that basic function but have an anonymous function (lambda) passed in. The code above won't change and you can reuse it in other projects or cases.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) hope this also helps for similar future cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not case of scoping. The problem is that `loader.load` is **asynchronous** function call (like AJAX). So you should use *callback* for example to make your code work properly.

Comment: Should the callback be the 3rd parameter of loader.load() or the second parameter of the anonymous function?

Comment: @Mknsri there is very many possible ways, one of them is answer provided by pid